# Angular 4: Async Pipe - Not able to read JSON FILE

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I am working on a demo for Aysnc pipe. One of method call, supposed to read data from JSON file for books. But I am getting 404 for JSON fine.[image]

I have added image of the project folders.
I have a book service as follows:-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import {Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Book } from './book';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {
    url = 'http://localhost:4200/books/books.json';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    // Returns Observable<Book[]>
    getBooksWithObservable(): Observable<Book[]> {
        console.log('getBooksWithObservable()');
        return this.http.get(this.url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
    // Returns Promise<Book[]>
    getBooksWithPromise(): Promise<Book[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-trailing-whitespace

    // Returns Observable<string>
    getCurrentTime(): Observable<string> {
        return new Observable<string>((observer: Subscriber<string>) => {
                    // 1 second interval
        setInterval(() => observer.next(new Date().toString()), 1000);
        });
    }

    // Returns Promise<Book>

    getBookSlowly(): Promise<Book> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
        const book = new Book();
        book.id = 100;
        book.name = 'jQuery Tutorials';
            // Delay by 3 second
            setTimeout(() => resolve(book), 3000);
          });
    }
}
```

Refer the following image for error in Chrome:-
[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you have to move your file inside your project, try to put it inside assets

```
url = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/books/books.json';
```

or you have to add your json file to assets array inside angular-cli.json

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "books",
        "books/books.json"
    ]
```

Comment: I added the entry in angular-cli.json file but still getting the same error.

Comment: url = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/books/books.json'; worked for me. Thanks alot for the same.