# Can't show data from local json file in browser

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rxjs

I want to show JSON data in browser so that model, provider, storage and condition displays in separate divs.
There is no error in console and i can't figure out where is the problem.
Link updated for stackblitz, kindly have a look into it.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/inhaq/for-SO)

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1htdt) is the link for stackblitz.

iphone.json

```
{
"model": [
    "iPhone 5",
    "iPhone 5s",
    "iPhone SE"
],
"provider": [
    "Unlocked",
    "AT&T"
],
"storage": [
    "16",
    "32"
],
"condition": [
    "Brand New",
    "Mint"
] 
}
```

sell.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

export interface Staticdata {
  model: Array<Model>;
  provider: Array<Provider>;
  storage: Array<Storage>;
  condition: Array<Condition>;
}

export interface Model {
  name: string;
}

export interface Provider {
  carrier: string;
 }

 export interface Storage {
   size: number;
 }

 export interface Condition {
   quality: string;
 }

 @Injectable()
 export class SellService {
  fileUrl = '../static-data/iphone.json';
  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {}

  getData(){
   return this.http.get(this.fileUrl);
   }

  }
```

sell-iphone.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SellService, Staticdata } from "../shared/sell.service";
import * as data from "../static-data/iphone.json";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sell-iphone',
  templateUrl: './sell-iphone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sell-iphone.component.css'],
  providers: [ SellService ]
})
export class SellIphoneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public sellService: SellService){
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  staticData : Staticdata;
  showData(){
    return this.sellService.getData().subscribe((data: Staticdata) => this.staticData = {
      model: data.model,
      provider: data.provider,
      storage: data.storage,
      condition: data.condition
    });
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is showData being called from? What does your HTML template look like?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let mode of model">
{{mode}}
</div>
I was trying with this in my html

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no `this.model`, do you mean `let mode of staticData.model`? Also, if your not calling `showData`, then this won't work

Comment: staticData.model shows error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

Comment: Where is your `showData()` called?

Comment: That's because you've not set staticData because you're not calling `showData`. You can change it to `staticData?.model` but you still won't see your data until you call `showData`

Comment: let me add this in stackblitz and it'll be nice if you try it there. Thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011096/4399281

Comment: @FatehMohamed did that, i think problem is in code

Comment: @user184994 from where should i call showData?

Comment: Maybe in `ngOnInit`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee thanks, it's not called, sorry for that. where should i call it?

Comment: @user184994 that causes some more errors, let me put this code in stackblitz.

Comment: `sell-iphone.component.html` can you post this?

Comment: @Inzimam `ngOnInit() { this.showData(); }` you can do this.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee edited my post to add live code on stackblitz, kindly check

Comment: @Inzimam None of the components have your code in them, did you save the stackblitz?

Comment: @user184994 Sorry, link updated

Comment: Stackblitz isn't working beacause it won't allow you to GET the json file. You can always upload to Github or something if you like

Comment: Let me put this on github

Comment: @user184994 Github repo added in post, kindly look into it

Comment: Sorry, doesn't build with ng build or ng serve

Comment: The `rxjs/observable` is giving a problem, its returning me undefined when subscribed check [this](https://angular-rm5lki.stackblitz.io) do a `npm install rxjs -g
npm cache clean` and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json must be like:

```
    {
    "model": [
        {
            "name": "iPhone 5"
        },
        {
            "name": "iPhone 5s"
        },
        {
            "name": "iPhone SE"
        }
    ],
    "provider": [
        {
            "carrier": "Unlocked"
        },
        {
            "carrier": "AT&T"
        }
    ],
    "storage": [
        {
            "size": "16"
        },
        {
            "size": "32"
        }
    ],
    "condition": [
        {
            "quality": "Brand New"
        },
        {
            "quality": "Mint"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you must transform the data you received. You can do it in the service better than in the component.

```
getData(){
   return this.http.get(this.fileUrl).pipe(map((res:any)=>{
     return {
        model:res.model.map(m=>{return {name:m}}),
        provider:res.provider.map(p=>{return{carrier:p}}),
        storage:res.storage.map(s=>{return{size:s}}),
        condition:res.condition.map(c=>{return{quality:c}})
     }
   })
  );
}
```

If you're using angular-cli, you must put your file.json in the folder "assets"

Comment: thanks Eliseo, I made my json like you mentioned above. how to receive this data in component?

Comment: read my comment. If you're using angular-cli. you must put your file iphone.json in the assets folder and do httpClient.get('assets/iphone.json'). angular-cli create all the files in a "dist" folder, and only copy "assets" folder. It's the reason because all the externals files you need must be in assets folder (json files, images files, config files...)

Comment: Thanks did that, but I'm newbie. Asking about how i can get these data in components and then show it in html? Thanks for helping so much, really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: how to subscribe to this observable in component?

Comment: in ngOnInit call to your function showData: ngOnInit(){this.showData()} or put the code of the function inside the ngOnInit

Comment: <div >
{{model.name}}
</div> this is not working in html , it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: model is an ARRAY, if model were an object you can write {{model?.name}}. This make that, if model has no value, not show anything -but not make error-. After, when model has value, you can see.

Comment: i tried that but error is still there although it display all values from json with or without ?